# Anything wrong with instantiating an object in a Model and returning the object with the Model values in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, models

Like performance issues or something? Basically I will have some Views whose data will be coming in across different models and I just want to have the data sent back to be the ones that I need, and really don't like the arrays CakePHP models send back.

So just get the aggregate data, transform it and populate the object then send that back to the controller to pass on to the view.

Yes it's extra work but if it doesn't cause any issues, I think it'll be worth it.

So any problems with this way of doing things? Thanks.

Comment: Show your code.

I would not change the array structure. If other people have to work with the code this might become a pain in the rear. I just had this kind of fun last week. Depending on for what you want to use the data you might have to restore the original structure so that other methods can work with it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Code hasn't been written yet, still in the planning stages. This will only be for views that display data. Writing to the DB will still be regular Cake. 

Like in the Dude model, I'd have a method called

`function getDude($id){
   $dude = $this->find->etc.
   $aggregatedata = etc.
   $theDude = new DudeViewModel($dude, $aggregatedata);
   return $theDude;
}`

Just a basic sample of what I want to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to objects would be small overhead but shouldn't pose any major issues performance wise. Though it could make maintaining the app difficult for others like burzum commented. By augmenting the way the framework works you will lose lot of its benefits. Eg. passing objects to views means the helpers won't be able to do any "magic". If you dislike the fact that CakePHP's models return arrays then perhaps you should not be using CakePHP.

Comment: Oh no worries then, thanks dude!

Don't foresee much of an issue with the helpers, might be a bit more work manually setting the values on the Form helpers but I think it should be fine as I believe any extra fields will carry over and we can just do a custom save method in the model. Was mostly concerned with the overhead. 

I had considered switching to another Framework, but I'll stick with Cake for 3.0.